# sample estimate of probability using R

Tags: r, statistics, probability

Suppose I have a random sample of 100 observations from a population with distribution Y=X^2, where X is normal. How do I calculate the sample estimate of P(Y<=2) using R? Here P() denotes probability. Does the following code help?

```
X=rnorm(100)
Y=X^2
prob(Y<=2)
```

Thanks beforehand

Comment: Perhaps try `sum(Y < 2)/length(Y)`

Comment: @markdly thanks for the response. But, why are we summing and dividing by the length? How does that relate to probability? Could you elaborate?

Comment: See this http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/old/5101/rlook.html

Comment: I may have misinterpreted your question. `sum(Y < 2)/length(Y)` is the probability `Y < 2` for one particular sample of 100 numbers.  This probability will vary each time a new sample is drawn. If instead you are interested in probability `Y < 2` for the population distribution then based on the example above I think you will want `pnorm(sqrt(2))`

Answer (score 0):

If `y = x^2`, then `P(y <= 2) = P(x^2 <= 2) = P(x <= sqrt(2))`

So, the answer is:

```
pnorm(sqrt(2)) - pnorm(-sqrt(2))
# [1] 0.8427008
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @markdly the required code is 
    sum(Y<=2)/length(Y)

This calculates the probability that the sample observations are less than or equal to 2, which varies with sample.
The above answer given by @akond, which basically calculates the exact probability could also be derived from
    pchisq(2,1)